# excluding a column in csv file with regex

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

Is there any way to exclude/delete/replace one field from a csv file with some regexp in notepad++?

I have a csv file with some data like this:

```
'1','data1','data2','data3','data4','data5','data6','data7','data8','data9',
'data10','data11','data12','data13','data14','data15','data16','data17','data18',
'data19','data20','data21','data22','data23','\'data24 with some commas, 
here and there and some "double quotes", and fullstops.','data25','data26'
```

The only problem I am facing is with `data24` WHERE I encounter  `\'` and then `""` and some wild characters like `,` and `.`. This is particularly fixed at 24 field. 
For the purpose of clarity, I have entered a newline here. But the entire text above is in juts one line.

Any ideas on how to solve?

Thanks.

Comment: how many fields are there in total - is it guaranteed to be 26?

Comment: no, that's not gonna help in notepad++ as quantifiers like `*`, `+`, `{24}` doesn't seem to work there.

Answer (score 2):

Not reliably. It is probably easiest to change the file with some tool which knows how to handle CSV (OpenOffice).

If you still want to use a regex, take a look at the [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), so that you match a single quote only if it is not preceded by a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Do you want to remove field number 24?

To get only **L fields from left** and **R fields from right** (thus, exclude fields L+1, ..., NF - R - 1, where NF is number of fields) and not to worry about weird characters in fields staying in between you can use following awk command:

awk 'BEGIN {FS=","; L=23; R=2} { for(i=1; i<=L+1; i++) printf($i); for(i=NF-R+1; i<=NF; i++) printf($i); print '\n'}' your_file

As Dave M [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037191/excluding-a-column-in-csv-file-with-regex/3037249#3037249) you can get tools like cut (and awk) for Windows from [here](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) (this particular package contains gawk which should work as well with the same command)

**Edit:** Yeah, download link at sourceforge seems not to work. You can get awk and cut from here:

**awk**: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm

**cut**: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm

Comment: This breaks when there are commas in any of the fields, (for example field 24 contains commas).

Comment: Well, as far as I understand the question, commas ARE ACTUALLY USED to seperate fields, only field number 24 has them in their content which is the essence of the problem.

Comment: @JPro: Ok then. So is there something wrong with my awk snippet? Or does it has to be done in Notepad++, period?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using something like Ruby's CSV library to read the file in, process it programmatically, and write it out again.